# What are the limitations of Hilbert Curves?

Tags: hilbert-spaces

Is there a Hilbert curve for every space? as I understanding it in layman terms, it's a way to order a space sequentially which visits every place once.

Does it work with continuous spaces, or just discrete? Are there certain limitations of dimensionality that you cannot use a Hilbert curve to explore?

I guess I'm asking if everything can be serialized?

What must I understand to understand the boundary of the Hilbert Curve concept?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it was well known just after Peano's 1890 paper appeared that extensions to higher dimensions can be made, as Peano mentions a continuous curve filling a $3$-dimensional cube at the end of his 1890 paper. The first published explicit construction I know of is: Jean-Armand Marie Joseph de Séguier (1862-1935), [*Courbe remplissant un cube à* $n$ *dimensions*](http://www.numdam.org/article/BSMF_1901__29__312_1.pdf) [Curve filling a cube of $n$ dimensions], **Bulletin de la Société Mathématique de France** 29 (1901), 312-314. **(continued)**

Comment: I believe what de Séguier did was to carry out the details for a generalization of Hilbert's 1891 approach. For further generalizations, see [the Hahn-Mazurkiewicz theorem](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Hahn-Mazurkiewicz+theorem%22&filter=0).

Comment: A Hilbert curve (a continuous surjective map from $[0,1] \to [0,1]^2$) does not "visit every place once". Many, many points are visited multiple times - some of them may even be visited infinitely many times. While continuous injective maps, continuous surjective maps, and discontinuous bijective maps all exist, there is no continuous bijective map between $[0,1]$ and $[0,1]^2$.